# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float (Pytorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I've tried many times to fix, also I've used the example codes from functional.py then I got my  same "loss" value. How can I fix this?

My libraries

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    import pandas as pd
    from torch.autograd import Variable
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,TensorDataset
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    import warnings
    import os
    import torchvision
    import torchvision.datasets as dsets
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
```

Data set of Mnis

```
    
    train=pd.read_csv("train.csv",dtype=np.float32)
    
    
    targets_numpy = train.label.values
    features_numpy = train.loc[:,train.columns != "label"].values/255 # normalization
    
    
    features_train, features_test, targets_train, targets_test = train_test_split(features_numpy,
                                                                                 targets_numpy,test_size = 0.2,
                                                                                 random_state = 42) 
   
    featuresTrain=torch.from_numpy(features_train)
    targetsTrain=torch.from_numpy(targets_train)
    
    
    featuresTest=torch.from_numpy(features_test)
    targetsTest=torch.from_numpy(targets_test)     
    
    
    batch_size=100
    n_iterations=10000
    num_epochs=n_iterations/(len(features_train)/batch_size)
    num_epochs=int(num_epochs)
    
    
    train=torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(featuresTrain,targetsTrain) 
    test=torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(featuresTest,targetsTest)
    
    print(type(train))
    
    
    
    train_loader=DataLoader(train,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)
    test_loader=DataLoader(test,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)
    print(type(train_loader))
    
    plt.imshow(features_numpy[226].reshape(28,28))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title(str(targets_numpy[226]))
    plt.show()
```

Here is my model

```
  

    class ANNModel(nn.Module):  
      
      def __init__(self,input_dim,hidden_dim,output_dim):
        super(ANNModel,self).__init__()
    
        
        self.fc1=nn.Linear(input_dim,hidden_dim)
        
        self.relu1=nn.ReLU()
    
        
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(hidden_dim,hidden_dim)
        
        self.tanh2=nn.Tanh()
    
       
    
        
        self.fc4=nn.Linear(hidden_dim,output_dim)
    
      def forward (self,x): #forward ile elde edilen layer lar bağlanır
        
        out=self.fc1(x)
        
        out=self.relu1(out)
    
        
        out=self.fc2(out)
        
        out=self.tanh2(out)
    
       
        
    
        
        out=self.fc4(out)
        return out  
      
    input_dim=28*28
    hidden_dim=150  
    output_dim=10 
    
    
    
    model=ANNModel(input_dim,hidden_dim,output_dim)
    
    
    error=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
    
    learning_rate=0.02
    optimizer=torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)
```

where the problem is

```
 

   
    count=0
    loss_list=[]
    iteration_list=[]
    accuracy_list = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
      for i,(images,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        train=Variable(images.view(-1,28*28))
        labels=Variable(labels)
        #print(labels)
        #print(outputs)  
       
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
        #forward propagation
        outputs=model(train)
    
       
       
        #outputs=torch.randn(784,10,requires_grad=True)
        ##labels=torch.randn(784,10).softmax(dim=1)
        loss=error(outputs,labels)
        
        
        
       
        loss.backward()
    
        
        optimizer.step()
        
        count+=1
         
        if count %50 ==0:
          
          
          correct=0
          total=0
          
         
          for images,labels in test_loader:
            test=Variable(images.view(-1,28*28))
    
            
            outputs=model(test)
    
            
            predicted=torch.max(outputs.data,1)[1] #mantık???
    
           
            total+= len(labels)
    
            
            correct+=(predicted==labels).sum()
    
          accuracy=100  *correct/float(total)
         
          loss_list.append(loss.data)
          iteration_list.append(count)
          accuracy_list.append(accuracy)
          if  count %500 ==0 :
           
           print('Iteration: {}  Loss: {}  Accuracy: {} %'.format(count, loss.data, accuracy))
```

Which gives

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-9-9e53988ad250> in <module>()
         26     #outputs=torch.randn(784,10,requires_grad=True)
         27     ##labels=torch.randn(784,10).softmax(dim=1)
    ---> 28     loss=error(outputs,labels)
         29 
         30 
    
    2 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
       2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
       2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
    -> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
       2847 
       2848 
    
    RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

Comment: What is the net supposed to do? Classify images across 10 classes?

Comment: Exactly, we have 10 classes that need to be classified.

Comment: In this case then your network is missing a very important final activation layer using a `softmax` function, since you are interested in the probabilities of any sample belonging to 10 *mutually exclusive* classes.

Comment: but Instructor said; "PyTorch does automatically apply softmax" and we don't need any code blocks. If not what can I write instead?

Comment: You can define get a softmax function like `self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)`. Now apply this after your final output in the `forward` function. So `out = self.softmax(out)` and return this value.

Comment: @ShahadMahmud thank you ,i got this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that the dtype of the tensor "labels" is FloatTensor. However, nn.CrossEntropyLoss expects a target of type LongTensor. This means that you should check the type of "labels". if its the case then you should use the following code to convert the dtype of "labels" from FloatTensor to LongTensor:

```
loss=error(outputs,labels.long())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
targetsTrain=torch.from_numpy(targets_train)
targetsTest=torch.from_numpy(targets_test)
```

in these lines you have to add these codes:

```
targetsTrain=torch.from_numpy(targets_train).type(torch.LongTensor)#data type is long
targetsTest=torch.from_numpy(targets_test).type(torch.LongTensor)#data type is long
```

then it works without problem